# How to get existing instance of UITabBarController?

Tags: objective-c, ios6, xcode4.6

I have an iPad app (XCode 4.6, ios 6.2, ARC and Storyboards).  I need to get **existing** instance of the UITabBarController.  This is my code, but it's obviously wrong.  How do I correct it?

```
    UITabBarController *tabBarController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"tabBarController"];
[tabBarController setSelectedIndex:0];
```

Comment: where are you calling this code from?

Comment: another view controller

Comment: yes, it is set to "tabBarController"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are instantiating a new `UITabBarController` instance as the method name suggests.

If you are in the context of a `UIViewController` within the `UITabBarController`, just use

```
self.tabBarController
```

If the context is not in `UITabBarController`, `self.tabBarController` return nil.

Comment: Fantastic!  (why didn't I think of that? :D )  Thank you!